# you may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. ...vuetify.min.css

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

you may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. ...vuetify.min.css

Answer (score 0):

You can import it in yout main.js

```
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
```

for this to work you should have css-loader in you webpack config

In your webpack

```
module: {
   loaders: [
     { test: /\.css$/, loader: "css-loader" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How to access webpack config in vue cli 3